# Connection to remote elastic search cluster fails

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to connect to a remote elastic search cluster using Transport client.

```
public class AuthenticationExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 4) {
            System.out.println("Usage :\njava -jar jarFile.jar clusterName hostIP port index");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        String clusterName = args[0];
        String hostName = args[1];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        String index = args[3];
        Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", clusterName).build();
        TransportClient esClient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(hostName), port));
        esClient.threadPool().getThreadContext().putHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeBase64("user:password".getBytes()));
        System.out.println("Initialized successfully.");
        boolean isIndexExists = false;
        isIndexExists = esClient.admin().indices().prepareExists(index).execute().actionGet().isExists();
        if (isIndexExists) {
            System.out.println("Is Index " + index + " Exists? " + isIndexExists);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Index " + index + " does not exist");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, as

java -jar jarFile.jar clusterName XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 9300 indexName

I am getting the following exception
NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: ...

Also when I hit the endpoint using,

curl -XGET -u user:password http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200

I am getting the response as follows,

```
{
  "name" : "XfJq4ed",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "26yoM76iT8i-eo8k0E8y4g",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.4.0",
    "build_hash" : "780f8c4",
    "build_date" : "2017-04-28T17:43:27.229Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Kindly give me a solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you allowed the HTTP module?

You can see the avalaible options here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/modules-http.html

Comment: Since it is remote server, I am aware of only the username and password.  I have no idea of HTTP module.  Any other way to do from the java client side?

Comment: So probably http is enabled, if it's a remote server.

Please, check out this link too:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/modules-network.html

'discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts' - Defaults to ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]